# How can I create backup script from diagram in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I create a script from all object (tables / trigger / stored procedure / function ...) in my database.

I generated this script from SQL Server Management Studio. I can recreate my database with this scrips on the other server. But I miss all diagrams of my database after run my script for create another database.

Therefore, I need create backup script from all diagrams that exist in my database.

I need execute this script on the destination database for recreating all my diagrams.

I found this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43076/Backup-SQL-Diagrams-In-Less-Than-5-Minutes). but i need some thinks that create all script (Insert Command) automatically.

Comment: Have a look here its very detailed description of what your are trying to do http://gursethi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/how-to-take-backup-of-database-diagrams.html

Comment: Can you clarify **what** it is you are trying to back up? You say "I want create back up script only from my diagrams" do you want to save the _diagram_ or the _objects_ in the diagram?

Comment: your link is not work :404 - Not Found

Comment: Ok i change my question.

Comment: The link Muhammed Ali gave works for me.

Comment: @loup - So you want to reverse engineer a database diagram to create the tables? You have only a copy of the diagram and no access to the original database?

Comment: Maybe i have some filtering in my country?!?

Comment: @Tony : no i don't want reverse engineering to create my table from my diagram! I recreate my database with a script and then i need back (recreate) all my diagram.

Comment: @loup - I understand now, sorry, I was just trying to clarify your question :)

Answer (score 8):

I have found a reasonable solution. The problem is that Management Studio cannot display more that 65535 characters for Non-XML data, and cannot be set to display more than 65535.

See code for documentation :)

Backup script:

```
-- 1. Read from DB, using XML to workaround the 65535 character limit
declare @definition varbinary(max)
select @definition = definition from dbo.sysdiagrams where name = 'ReportingDBDiagram' 

select
    '0x' + cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:variable("@definition") )', 'varchar(max)')
for xml path('')

-- 2. Open the result XML in Management Studio
-- 3. Copy the result
-- 4. Paste this in backup script for @definition variable
```

Restore script:

```
declare @definition varbinary(max)
set @definition = 0xD0CF -- Paste 0x0 value from Backup script

-- Create diagram using 'official' Stored Procedure
exec dbo.sp_creatediagram
    @diagramname = 'ReportingDBDiagramCopy',
    @owner_id = null,
    @version = 1,
    @definition = @definition
```

Comment: Still very helpful, even with Azure SQL. Thanks!

Comment: Error while open Diagram : "The docfile has been currupted."

Answer (score 2):

Scripting your database does not include diagrams as they are not *server objects* in the same way as a table or stored procedure; they exist as data in the `sysdiagrams` table.

A similar question on SO asked [How do you migrate SQL Server Database Diagrams to another Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527327/how-do-you-migrate-sql-server-database-diagrams-to-another-database)

The accepted answer is to copy the contents of the `sysdiagrams` table to the new database, so you could include the table contents in your script. The [answer with the most up-votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/527344/243925) has a link to a way of [scripting diagrams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15080/Script-SQL-Server-2005-diagrams-to-a-file).

I've tried backing up and then restoring a database to the same server, deleting the diagram I had created (I only had one) and then running the following query:

```
INSERT  INTO database2.dbo.sysdiagrams
        ( 
         NAME
        ,principal_id
        ,version
        ,DEFINITION
        )
        SELECT  NAME
               ,principal_id
               ,version
               ,DEFINITION
        FROM    database1.dbo.sysdiagrams
```

The diagram was successfully restored, **however** I did do this on a restored backup, I should really test it with a new database generated from a script.

**UPDATE:**

I scripted a database and then created a new database from it. When trying to rebuild the diagrams using an `INSERT` statement I got the error

[image]

So although it seems possible it's not trivial to create diagrams in a new database created from a script. Go with the answer given regarding scripting diagrams and modify it for your own needs.

Perhaps you can investigate further and post your own answer :)

Comment: +1: Scripting database diagrams to a script/text file before running seems to hit some sort of file limits and gives the "docfile has been corrupted". Copying it directly, using a cross database `insert` like yours seems to work 100% of the time. When I get time I will see if it is just the line length limit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick & dirty method I use. Since the query window won't display the full varbinary(max) value of the definition field, but the XML editor will, I output the rows to XML as follows:

1. Run the following query on the server/database that contains the diagrams:

   ```
   SELECT 'INSERT sysdiagrams(name,principal_id,diagram_id,version,definition) VALUES('''+name+''','
   +CONVERT(varchar(2),principal_id)+','+CONVERT(varchar(2),diagram_id)+','+CONVERT(varchar(2),version)+','
   +'0x' + CAST('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:column("definition"))','varchar(max)') +')'
   FROM RCSQL_ClaimStatus.dbo.sysdiagrams
   FOR XML PATH
   ```
2. Click on the generated link to open the XML result, and ctrl-a & ctrl-c to copy all rows generated.
3. Paste that output back into your query window. I usually paste it between a pair of IDENTITY_INSERT's like this:

   ```
   --TRUNCATE TABLE sysdiagrams
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT sysdiagrams ON;
   <row>INSERT sysdiagrams(name,principal_id,diagram_id,version,definition) VALUES('ERD1',1,1,1,0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE100000...)</row>
   <row>INSERT sysdiagrams(name,principal_id,diagram_id,version,definition) VALUES('ERD2',1,2,1,0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE100000...)</row>
   <row>INSERT sysdiagrams(name,principal_id,diagram_id,version,definition) VALUES('ERD3',1,3,1,0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE100000...)</row>
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT sysdiagrams OFF;
   ```
4. Remove the row & /row XML tags from your inserts, and run them on the target server. You can truncate the sysdiagrams table if you're replacing all values with new values.

Comment: that was the solution the worked well for me... thank you very much!