# sql 2008r2 can I copy a diagram from database to database and retain relationships

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema, relationships

My objective is to get relationships from database A to database B. Please note I can not do a backup and restore, this is not an option.

These three sets of relationships are in three diagrams and having never copied a diagram from A to B before I was thinking that, if I did this the relationships may also come over. The copy went great, simply moving the records from `a.sysDiagrams to b.sysDiagrams` was easy.

But no relationships came across, damn.  What is the best method to copy diagrams including the relationships from A to B?

A fair amount of time was put into creating these. We often want to move a set of tables from Database to database. Most of the time these are on different servers.

Comment: The diagram displays relationships - it doesn't contain them. You'll need to script that. Look into software like RedGates Compare programs and similar if you do not want to do it yourself.

Comment: Hi Allan thank you for clarifying that.  This is very unfortunate, it would be a great feature.  I don't even see the point of copying them if all that comes across is a bunch of tables to be honest.  So except for a backup/restore does sql2008 really have no way to move a bunch of tables and relationships?   Thanks again

Comment: I don't know where diagrams get these things from but I suspect it is foreign keys (which in turn require primary keys). If you script those across do they appear in your diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for completeness the comment made by Allan S is the answer to this post. I don't believe I can accept his comment since it was only a comment and not an answer?

I would be very interested to know if there is a way to copy a 2008 SQLServer diagram and include the relationships.  I assume there is not.

Answer (score -1):

There are so many option without backup-restore, you can script the diagrams to a .sql file...first check that diagrams list

```
-- List all database diagrams
SELECT * FROM [SourceDB].[dbo].sysdiagrams
```

Check similar question : 
[How to export a SQL Server 2008 Database Diagram to another DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019560/how-to-export-a-sql-server-2008-database-diagram-to-another-db)

Even via visual-Data tool you can  :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175868%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

**Updated**
Check this link :

http://forums.asp.net/t/1790223.aspx?Making+ER+Diagram+from+SQL+Server+2008+Database
[How do you migrate SQL Server Database Diagrams to another Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527327/how-do-you-migrate-sql-server-database-diagrams-to-another-database)

https://superuser.com/questions/578090/how-to-database-model-in-visio-2013

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15080/Script-SQL-Server-diagrams-to-a-file

Comment: Hi Ajay sorry if I wasnt clear.  copying diagrams is not my issue.  I did this but the relationships did not come across.  My question was how to do this and retain the relationships?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Ok, is the script not help you? and what about last link?

Comment: Let me try the last option to check.  But I suspect me copying them from database A.sysDiagrams to database B.sysDiagrams fails to bring relationships I doubt copying them using management studio UI will.  In your opinion should primaryKeys and foriegn keys come across when copying diagram from database A to B??

Comment: No the outcome is the same.  I am starting to think copying a database diagram never carries PK's and FK's (although I am not finding anything that states this ) Does anyone know if this is possible or am I looking at wrong method?

Comment: BTW the last link was no good. its all about copying tables between diagrams.  If you read my original post again this is not what I am trying to do

Comment: ok, I will check again... I fill the script will help you.no issue.